# How to format date into specific language?

Tags: c#, date

Now given a date 19-June-2014, my objective is to convert the given date to 19日06月2014年.

日 = Day

月 = Month

年 = Year

I've tried using `CultureInfo: ZH-CN` and in format **dd MMM yyyy** but here is what I got: 19 六月2014. The month is partially correct but the numeric(6) turned into mandarin as well, which doesnt fulfill my need. And note that the day and year doesnt reflect changes. May I know what went wrong?

Comment: Maybe **Satellite Assembly** would have answer for you to localize your application in different locations! :)

Comment: Manually replacing of the `-` characters is not an option?

Comment: The usual thing in Chinese is the other way around, as in format `"D"` (capital D), try `yourDateTime.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("zh-CN"))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do `yourDateTime.ToString("dd日MM月yyyy年")`. That is `"dd\u65E5MM\u6708yyyy\u5E74"` if your C# source file is in an encoding (like an old Western codepage) that won't allow usual characters.